# Wrong resource is used

Tags: android, android-resources

I have two layouts for different screen size:

```
layout
layout-w580dp
```

Display metrics log for portrait and landscape orientation:

```
DisplayMetrics{density=1.3312501, width=800, height=1280, scaledDensity=1.5841876, xdpi=216.0, ydpi=216.0}
DisplayMetrics{density=1.3312501, width=1280, height=800, scaledDensity=1.5841876, xdpi=216.0, ydpi=216.0}
```

Potrait orientation has `800/1.5841876=504dp`, so resource from `layout` folder sould be used.
Landscape orientation has `1200/1.5841876=704dp`, so resource from `layout-w580dp` folder sould be used.
However, in both orientation resource is obtained from `layout-w580dp` folder.
What causes that issue?

Comment: Would `layout-land` be more appropriate here?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i consider it for tablets, they can have enough space for wide layout in portrait orientation

Comment: I don't know the rules for how Android chooses which layout folder to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) the formula to convert from dp to physical pixels is `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`. Since we want to convert in the opposite direction, we need to solve for `dp`: `dp = px * 160 / dpi`. For your two examples, we have the following values and calculation:

1. `px = 800` (width), `dpi = 216` (xdpi) `dp = px * 160 / dpi = 800 * 160 / 216 = 592.59`.
2. `px = 1280` (width), `dpi = 216` (xdpi) `dp = px * 160 / dpi = 1280 * 160 / 216 = 948.15`.

In both cases, the width is more than 580 dp.